# C++ threads race condition simulation

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

Here is a C++ program that runs `10` times with `5` different threads and each thread increments the `value` of `counter` so the final output should be `500`, which is exactly what the program is giving output. But i cant understand why is it giving `500` every time the output should be different as the increment operation is not `atomic` and there are no locks used so the program should give out different outputs in each case.

edit to increase probability of race condition i increased the loop count but still couldn't see any varying output

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

struct Counter {
    int value;

    Counter() : value(0){}

    void increment(){
        value = value + 1000;
    }
};

int main(){
    int n = 50000;
    while(n--){
    Counter counter;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&counter](){
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i){
                counter.increment();
            }
        }));
    }

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << counter.value << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, it *shouldn't* be different. It *could* be, but there are no guarantees either way.

Comment: this is really dependent also on what hardware you run it etc. Race conditions are never "easy" to reproduce.

Comment: I also get consistent results on my computer, but changing 100 to 100000 makes it change. It's pretty easy to guess why. While there are no guarantees, on some systems, 100 iterations is less than the time it takes to create another thread, push it to the vector, etc.

Comment: First, look into assembler and make sure that the inner loop is not optimized so hard that the whole loop is removed. The optimization should be disabled if `Counter::value` is declared `volatile`. Second, write the time before and after the loop and see if threads actually work in parallel.

Comment: gcc with `-O2` for example does compile the lambda into a single add instruction, no matter the number of iterations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're just lucky :)

Compiling with clang++ my output is not always 500:

```
500
425
470
500
500
500
500
500
432
440
```

Comment: i tried many times even increased wile loop to 500 but still same output 500

Comment: To raise probability of using wrong `value`'s value, try increasing `for` loop and marking `value` as `volatile`

Comment: Trying to increase more I was able to reproduce the problem: https://ideone.com/7S461A

Comment: Thnakyou so much!

Answer (score 5):

**Note**

Using g++ with -fsanitize=thread -static-libtsan:

```
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=13871)
  Read of size 4 at 0x7ffd1037a9c0 by thread T2:
    #0 Counter::increment() <null> (Test+0x000000509c02)
    #1 main::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const <null> (Test+0x000000507ed1)
    #2 _M_invoke<> /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1531 (Test+0x0000005097d7)
    #3 operator() /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1520 (Test+0x0000005096b2)
    #4 _M_run /usr/include/c++/5/thread:115 (Test+0x0000005095ea)
    #5 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b8c7f)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7ffd1037a9c0 by thread T1:
    #0 Counter::increment() <null> (Test+0x000000509c17)
    #1 main::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const <null> (Test+0x000000507ed1)
    #2 _M_invoke<> /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1531 (Test+0x0000005097d7)
    #3 operator() /usr/include/c++/5/functional:1520 (Test+0x0000005096b2)
    #4 _M_run /usr/include/c++/5/thread:115 (Test+0x0000005095ea)
    #5 <null> <null> (libstdc++.so.6+0x0000000b8c7f)
```

shows the race condition. (Also, on my system the output shows results different than 500).

The options for g++ are explained in the documentage for g++ (e.g.: man g++). See also: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki#threadsanitizer.

Comment: After a bit of thinking I understood the output of the answer, but maybe also for others: can you just add a bit of explanation about the options?

Answer (score 4):

Just because your code has race conditions does not mean they occur. That is the hard part about them. A lot of times they only occur when something else changes and timing is different.

here are several issues: incrementing to 100 can be done really fast. So your threads may be already halfway done before the second one is started. Same for the next thread etc. So you never know you have really 5 in parallel.

You should create a **barrier** at the beginning of each thread to make sure they start all at the same time.

Also maybe try a bit more than "100" and only 5 threads. But it all depends on the system / load / timing. etc.

Answer (score 2):

> to increase probability of race condition i increased the loop count
>   but still couldn't see any varying output

Strictly speaking you have data race in this code which is Undefined Behavior and therefore you cannot reliably reproduce it.

But you can rewrite `Counter` to some "equivalent" code with artificial delays in `increment`:

```
struct Counter {
    int value;

    Counter() : value(0){}

    void increment(){
        int val=value;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        ++val;
        value=val;
    }
};
```

I've got the following output with this counter which is far less than `500`:

```
100
100
100
100
100
101
100
100
101
100
```